TSQL Add a new column in the middle of the table without dropping
I've got to add a new column to an existing very large table (more than 1bln rows) in our SQL server. This column should be placed in the middle of the table. When I execute alter statement with adding a new column, then the new column is placed at the end of the table.
If the table was sufficiently smaller, I would just do a table drop and then add a column in the process of creating the table and then let the insert into, but here unfortunately the size of the table is huge and the process of inserting the data would take at least a couple of days.
Can I ask for your help?

"This column should be placed in the middle of the table." No, it shouldn't, it should be placed at the end of the table and your SELECT statements should return it in the middle or your application display it in the middle. How your data is defined and how it is displayed are entirely different things. Where ordinal positions your columns are in your table, and what order you display them have no relationship. You do not need to do what you are asking. This is a classic XY Problem.

Why do yo think you need to add the column in the middle? Maybe if we know that, we can help you solve the real problem. (Because @ThomA is right.)

Relational databases have no formal concept of "Middle of a table". There is no obligation for the database to  preserve the order of columns given in the create table statement, and no obligation for the database to, for example, use that same order with a select * query (which you should also be avoiding). That we see this behavior commonly is simply a happy convenience, and NOT defined behavior for the tool in any way. When you have times where order matters. such as for logical groupings of related values, you MUST specify columns in order at retrieval. No exceptions!

Thank you for your replies. I fully understand them, but my current employer has specific rules for the creation of tables and their appearance. At the beginning of the table is the key information and at the end of the table are the audit columns such as the date of insertion, who did it and what was the process.
The table currently has company stock data and has 2 business dates that are held as a date. I have been given the task of adding the date in numeric form as a suitable combination of these 2 dates and then replacing all the joins in dwh to this number, this is an optimisation.

There is no way to insert a column in the middle without rebuilding the table, and for reasons stated above, you should not care or be dependent on the column location. But, ...if you do care ..., you could create a view that selects the table contents in the desired column order and use that view where needed. As an extreme measure, you could even rename the original table and create a view in its place. Most (all?) SQL Server DML operations will accept a view anyplace they accept a table, and (I believe) there is little or no performance penalty.

This table has more than 1bln rows, so view will kill performance of the table

"View will kill performance of the table" - What makes you think that? While a poorly designed or misused view can cause performance issues (particularly those including unnecessary joins, subselects, and aggregations not needed for all usages), a simple view like this is just a passthrough to the table. The query optimizer will see right through it as if the original table were referenced directly. See this db<>fiddle that shows  execution plans for several operations against both a table and a view. (I'd welcome any comments pointing out any exceptions.)

@TN: one disadvatage of using a view instead of a table is that you cannot use hints to force specific indexes for different queries. But I doubt that the OP already uses such hints.

Another approach is to: (0) Increased DB size. (1) Configure a trigger or change tracking to start recording the PKs of all added, updated, and deleted rows. It may be necessary to also track the last-changed date/time. (2) Slowly start building a new copy of the table with the columns defined as desired. (3) Once the initial copy is complete, use the tracked PKs to compare and refresh any changed data. (4) Repeat step 3 as needed. (5) During a maintenance window, refresh one last time, perform a couple of renames to cut over to the new table and ensure that all dependencies are also updated.

How did you manage to solve the problem?

As pointed out in the comments, your requirement to add the column in a specific place is probably due to (a) a meaningless convention or (b) poor design choices in some other parts of your application code.
However, if there are not many columns after the desired place of the new column and the data in those columns is static, you could remove and add those columns again; to keep the data, you could first add those columns with different names, copy the data, drop the original column and rename the new column.
For example, lets's suppose that this is the existing table:
CREATE TABLE YourTable (
    ThePK INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstColumn INT NOT NULL,
    CreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL
)

If you want to add SecondColumn after FirstColumn (before CreateDate), you could do this:
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD SecondColumn INT NULL

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD NewCreateDate DATETIME NULL

GO
UPDATE dbo.YourTable SET NewCreateDate = CreateDate

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN NewCreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable DROP COLUMN CreateDate

EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.YourTable.NewCreateDate','CreateDate','COLUMN'

However, there are potential issues with this solution, due to the concurrent changes during the operation:

During the UPDATE statement, new rows may be added, which will not have values in the NewCreateDate column. To solve this, you could repeat the UPDATE, adding a WHERE NewCreateDate IS NULL clause and an index on this column, to speed-up the operation.
Between the last two statements, if anything tries to access the CreateDate column, it would fail. To solve this, you could wrap those two statements in a transaction.
The solution is inapplicable if the columns at the end could be updated (for example if you have a ModifyDate column). To solve this, you would need to change the stored procedures which access this table. Another workaround would be to use a view.

Considering all these issues, you may want to give up on the requirement to put the new column in a specific position.

An interesting concept (essentially shifting all of the intermediate columns to the right with a combination of modify type, copy, and rename), but I think the underlying operations may involve multiple table rebuilds - the same issue the OP was trying to avoid. There are added complexities in adjusting indexes, foreign keys, and other constraints so that they continue to reference the intended columns.
